# Можно ли научиться ставить знаки препинания только на основе интонации?

Tags: пунктуация, интонация

«Конечно нельзя!» – скажете вы. А если попробовать в качестве эксперимента? Хотя бы для того, чтобы понять, что интонационный принцип является ведущим и требует **минимальных грамматических знаний**, связанных  в основном со структурой  предложения.  Попробовать-то  можно, но **только зачем нам всё это нужно?**

Правила в языке можно сравнить с законами в природе: в обоих случаях мы наблюдаем явление, пытаясь понять его закономерность. Физики на основании изучения практического материала создали теорию электричества, и ее правильность проверена опытом, так как мы научились управлять этой материей. Похожая задача стоит перед лингвистами: мы наблюдаем природу живого языка, стараемся понять его законы, изучить грамматику, чтобы научиться пользоваться этими законами в практической речи, устной и письменной.  **И если нам трудно это сделать, значит, наше понимание  природы языка несовершенно и нуждается в коррекции.**

Рассмотрим, к примеру, правила пунктуации, на основании чего они созданы?  Знаки препинания делят письменный текст на  отдельные части и определяют смысловые отношения между этими частями. Ту же функцию выполняет интонация – с помощью пауз различной длительности,  с помощью повышения и понижения голоса, изменения темпа речи. Образно говоря, **существует  зеркальное отражение устной речи в речи письменной.**

Но мы не умеем правильно говорить,  скажете вы, наша речь **строится интуитивно.** Только на основании интуиции мы меняем порядок слов в предложении, хотя в действительности тем самым  определяем нужную расстановку логических ударений, даже не догадываясь об этом.  Но если мы действительно не умеем говорить, то надо изучать в школе не только орфографию, но и правильную устную речь, чтобы пользоваться ею **не интуитивно, а  разумно.**

**И вопросы:**  Считаете ли вы  правила пунктуации оптимальными для пользования и изучения?  Лично вы всегда пользуетесь правилами  при написании любых текстов?  Почему расстановка трех основных знаков (запятой, двоеточия и тире) требует огромного количества правил?  Можно ли  и нужно ли что-то изменить?

Спасибо за ваше внимание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя, пробовал. Отличаясь хорошей сообразительностью, неплохим слухом и даже некоторыми актёрскими способностями (в детские годы регулярно побеждал на конкурсах чтецов) запятые в диктантах ставил на слух. В этом случае получается около двух пунктационных ошибок на страницу текста. Если ориентироваться только на собственную "музыку языка" порядка четырёх ошибок на страницу текста формата А4.

Касаясь изучения знаков препинания, мне было бы гораздо проще, если бы я получил объяснение сути этих знаков вместо кучи правил, но это индивидуально. В школьные годы я неверно интерпретировал, что запятая - это короткая пауза, а тире - длинная, отсюда и пошли мои ошибки.

Comment: Художественная речь  однозначно связана с правильной  интонацией, но это в основном интуитивные знания. Поэтому очень важно определить в интонации основные структурные элементы и связать их с грамматической  структурой  предложения. Например, в распространенном простом предложении присутствуют различные паузы, связанные с физиологией речи, и только одна пауза, связанная с деление на тему-рему и изменением тона, но эти паузы не обозначаются знаками препинания. А паузы в осложненном и сложном предложениях знаками препинания обозначаются.

Comment: Это всё элементарные сведения, но никто ими практически не пользуется, предпочитая изучать десятки правил, хотя подсказка в речи всегда присутствует.

Comment: @Vera живая речь хуже формализуется и потому сложнее для объяснения. Учёные филологи только в последние годы стали изучать разговорную речь и до сих пор не понимают многие её особенности, а вы хотите, чтобы их объяснили на уровне школьника. Нет ничего более сложного, чем элементарные вещи.

Comment: Разговорная речь - это особый стиль речи, нам же приходится записывать любой стиль:  и книжный, и разговорный. Речь идет о знании нескольких базовых элементов интонации  (пауза, движение тона), которые выделить в предложении не представляет никакого труда, это доступно даже младшим школьникам. Например, все понимают, что такое повышение тона в конце вопросительного предложения или что такое перечислительная интонация.

Answer (score 3):

1. Нет. Во многих случаях правила противоречат интонации. Обычно это проблема "лишних" запятых, их столько не нужно в языке.
2. Практически не пользуюсь и не пытаюсь вспомнить какое-л. правило, кроме крайних случаев. Считаю, что принцип построения частного выведением из общего (т.е. из правил) полезен для обоснований и доказательств, но не для практической речи. В неясных случаях ориентируюсь на прецеденты, встречающиеся в печатных текстах - помогает зрительная память.
3. Потому что правила расстановки знаков привязаны не к интонации, а к принципам учебного расчленения речи на обороты. Эти обороты изучаются разрозненными разделами грамматики, поэтому отдельной системы пунктуации практически нет.
4. Исключить требование простановки запятых в случаях, когда это противоречит интонации и не влияет на смысл. Например, опускать в таких случаях запятые, проставленные вследствие двустороннего обособления оборота. Можно условно оставить такие запятые в учебных материалах с разборами предложения, например с пометкой в виде двукратной простановки (чтобы не вводить новые знаки). Начать можно с введения нормы на отбрасывание запятой после союза "и" - она всегда противоречит интонации.

Comment: Не могу согласиться с Вами, что у нас нет системы пунктуации.  Такая система существует, она вполне логична и в преобразовании, с моей точки зрения, не нуждается.  Система существует, но пользователи не понимают принципа ее действия, не пользуются ее широкими возможностями. Вот и получается, что в реальности система не работает, не помогает правильно записать и понять текст, вследствие чего люди вообще перестают ставить знаки препинания. Это все равно что есть очень умная машина, но нет хорошей инструкции по ее эксплуатации.

Answer (score 3):

Ставить знаки препинания по интуиции не всегда возможно. Русская пунктуации основана трех принципах: структурный принцип (синтаксический). Большинство знаков препинания зависят от структуры предложения: знаки препинания между частями сложного предложения, знаки препинания выделяющие разнообразные конструкции в составе простого предложения  (обособленные члены, однородные члены, обращения, вводные и др. конструкции и т.д.
Второй принцип - смысловой, и лишь третий - интонационный. Но всегда бывает совпадение между интонацией и знаками препинания.

Напр.: ***Под мышкой мальчик нёс какой-то узел и, повернув к пристани, стал спускаться по узкой и крутой тропинке (М. Лермонтов)*** между союзом и и деепричастием повернув запятая есть, а пауза в устной речи отсутствует; наоборот, перед этим союзом есть пауза, а запятой нет.
Что касается упрощения пунктуации, то, конечно, много чего стоит переформулировать, дополнить. Но все это нужно в основном для тех, кто имеет дело непосредственно с языком. Для школьников, думаю, пунктуация не представляет особого труда.

P.S. Вера, если Вы под " пользуетесь ли вы правилами..." имеете в виду расстановку знаков препинания, отвечу: безусловно, да! Однако в соц.сетях часто вижу, что многие пишут, не расставляя знаков препинания(особенно в Одноклассниках). Могу понять неграмотных, но когда грамотные пишут без знаков препинания - удивляет. Ведь от знаков препинания зависит смысл написанного.

Comment: Серж, у интонации есть одна интересная закономерность: она имеет ограниченные возможности и поэтому всегда соотносится со старшей структурой. Это означает, что отдельное словосочетание имеет собственную интонацию, а когда оно входит в предложение, то собственную интонацию утрачивает и становится строительным материалом для простого предложения. Если в предложении появляются  однородные члены, то интонация опять меняется и начинает выражать однородные отношения и т.д.

Comment: Поэтому полное интонационное совпадение со знаками препинания мы имеем в простых структурах, а в сложных следует учитывать ТРАНСФОРМАЦИЮ интонации. В целом можно сказать, что знаки препинания ставятся в соответствии с интонационно-грамматическим принципом, но при этом иногда действует только грамматический принцип (обособление деепричастного оборота после союза И), а иногда только интонационный принцип - так называемое интонационное (авторское или смысловое) тире.

Answer (score 2):

Да, на самом деле правилами я, например, пользуюсь далеко не всегда. Например, моя переписка в контакте порой является просто примером деградации с точки зрения русского языка. И ведь даже навязшей уже "нехваткой времени" это не объяснишь. А просто... Все пишут без точек, без запятых, вот и я постепенно стала писать так же. Хотя в последнее время я все-таки на это гораздо больше обращаю внимания.

По поводу тире, двоеточия и запятой (скорее даже больше тире и двоеточия): эти знаки многозначны, они как бы направляют нас в разные стороны, и это, наверное, связано с интонацией (вы ведь на это намекаете?). Но упрощений, мне кажется, не нужно. Правила - они на то и есть правила, в них могут и должны быть какие-то сложности.

Comment: Вообще говоря, даже на этом форуме мы нередко используем  разговорный стиль и не так часто пользуемся академическими тире и двоеточием, предпочитая запятые. Это нарушение правил? Отнюдь нет, ПРАВИЛА НЕЛЬЗЯ НАРУШАТЬ, и каждый выбранный знак должен им соответствовать.  А ОБЪЯСНЕНИЕ такое: если мы ставим запятую, то обозначаем неопределенные (присоединительные или распространительные) отношения между частями предложения; если ставим тире, то это уже взаимообусловленные отношения, и только двоеточие указывает на точный следственно-причинный их порядок.  Поэтому  и удобнее пользоваться запятой.